# azure service bus monitoring on a mac

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have found service bus explorer a windows application which will allow me to connect to the Azure Service Bus and look at my topics and subscription and the messages on the subscriptions. I need to be able to do this from my mac as I am developing connectivity to the service bus and need to be able to look at the messages on the subscription to see why they are not being processed etc.

I would have thought that the az cli would be useful to do this but I cannot see any az service bus options as of yet. If anyone knows of a service bus explorer equivalent for the mac that would be greatly appreciative otherwise if anyone has any other ways of me be able to look at the actual message on the subscription that would be great.

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Cerulean](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features), which is a cross-platform product from Cerebrata.

> Today, Cerulean enables you to manage your Azure Subscriptions, Azure Storage accounts, Azure Cosmos DB accounts, Azure Redis Cache accounts, Azure Service Bus accounts, and Azure Search accounts. Support for more Azure services will be added soon. It is highly customizable.

Unfortunately it's not free though. Costs roughly 10$ per month at the time of this writing.

Comment: Up to $25 a month for personal as of 13th Nov 2020.... that's expensive for what it is imo.

Comment: Now $39. 14th April 2021.

Comment: Actually there is a new and cheaper alternative, superbus.app (but not cross platform only macOS)